# Semantics of EACH_QUORUM with only one Cassandra data-centre

Tags: cassandra, consistency

The [documentation for Cassandra consistency levels](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/dml/dml_config_consistency_c.html) says about the `EACH_QUORUM` consistency level:

> A write must be written to the commit log and memtable on a quorum of replica nodes in all data centers. Used in multiple data center clusters...

What are the semantics of the `EACH_QUORUM` consistency level when there is only one data centre? I can think of two possibilities:

- The term "all" includes the case of there only being one, so `EACH_QUORUM` requires writes to be written on a quorum of nodes in the sole data centre.
- The consistency level is for use *only* when you have multiple data centres (the "Used in multiple data center clusters" wording is restrictive, not descriptive), and must not be used when you have only one data centre. In that case use `QUORUM` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some experimentation, using Cassandra 2.1.5 and the Datastax Java driver 2.1.5, I discovered that the *implemented* (if not the *intended* semantics) are that the `EACH_QUORUM` consistency level works only when you have more than one data-centre. The Java driver fails `EACH_QUORUM` writes when there is only one data-centre, throwing an `UnavailableException` that complains that 0 nodes are available. Writes using `QUORUM` work OK.

Therefore **do not use `EACH_QUORUM` consistency-level if you have only one data-centre**. Use `QUORUM` instead.